# Toggle classes (navbar burger menu [show, hide]) | works in 'develop' but not in 'build'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

In the Navbar.js component I want to be able to set state to true or false of the is-active css class, so that when the user presses the burger menu button, the menu shows or hides.

The code below works in the gatsby develop but not in the gatsby build.

There are no errors in 'build'.

Question: Why the code below does not work in gatsby build?

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'gatsby-link';

import logo from '../img/logo.svg';

class Navbar extends React.Component {

  state = { showMenu: false }

  toggleMenu = () => {
    this.setState({
      showMenu: !this.state.showMenu
    })
  }

  render() {
    const menuActive = this.state.showMenu ? 'is-active' : '';
    const burgerActive = this.state.showMenu ? 'is-active' : '';
      return (     
  <nav className="navbar">
  <div className="navbar-brand">
    <Link className="navbar-item" to="/">
      <img src={logo} style={{ width: '88px' }} itemprop="image" alt="" />
    </Link>
    <div className={`navbar-burger burger ${burgerActive}`} onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className={`navbar-menu ${menuActive}`} >
    <div className="navbar-start">
      <Link className="navbar-link" to="/" onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
        Home
      </Link>
      <Link className="navbar-link" to="/services" onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
        Services
      </Link>
      <Link className="navbar-link" to="/contact" onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
        Contact
      </Link>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>)
  }
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or anything? Just this piece of code doesn't tell much.

Comment: I don't get any errors in either 'develop' or 'build'

Comment: That might be "z-index" css problem, try changing your z-index to a high value, example: z-index: 400

Comment: Have you found any solution on this issue, if yes please post.